# Webview loading local html page slow in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Hi i am loading local html file after handling some javascript alerts on webchromeclient, 
But after i call webview's loadUrl method my local html page loads very slowly it waits about 20 seconds to load.

Here is my code below:

```
@Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
            JsResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        result.confirm();

        if (message.contains(GeneralConstants.ALERT_LOGIN_TIMUSER)) {
            String s[] = message.split(";");

            //Set ldap user 


            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mainMenu.html");

            return true;
        }
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this piece of code for a better performance

```
    AssetManager mgr = getContext().getAssets();
                 try {
                     InputStream in = mgr.open(FileName,AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);

                     String sHTML = streamToString(in);
                     in.close();

                     //display this html in the browser
                     WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                     w.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
                     w.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);                        

                 } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }



public static String StreamToString(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        if(in == null) {
            return "";
        }

        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];

        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }

        } finally {

        }

        return writer.toString();
    }
```

Comment: :Hello , I am using your code because I load a local html file(offline) and it delays to open.So, because getCpontext() is undefined insted of "AssetManager mgr = getContext().getAssets();" , I put Context mcontext; , mcontext=this,"AssetManager mgr =this.getApplicationContext().getAssets();".Also, instead of Filename inside mgr.open() I am putting the ""file:///android_asset/hello.html" , right?But it doesn't load at all the page.If you could help me..Thanks.(I upvoted)

Comment: instead using AssetManager mgr =this.getApplicationContext().getAssets(); us AssetManager mgr =this.getAssets();

also don't give full path give only name because in loadDataWithUrl mathod we are giving path to assets

Comment: :Unfortunately the page does not load at all.In mgr.open(FileName,,... I do  mgr.open("thename.htm",...),right?In order to load the page (slow) I must use "loadUrl".It doesn't work with "loadDataWithBaseURL".have you any idea?Thank you

Comment: i think there is some problem in your code could you provide your code