# Android webview apply start too slowly.

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I created an android application. It uses a `WebView` to upload local html. But it starts very slowly. It uploads the page in about 10 seconds. Why it is so slow? What method can let the application starts faster?

Comment: I am not sure what "uses a webview to upload local html" means?
Do you mean you load a local html with webview?

Comment: @wayne_bai ya,that is my meaning. thank you!

Comment: How can network speed possibly affect a local action? If all the contents on the local html are in fact local, network speed won't have anything to do with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this -
This will enable cache in your webview thus might help you load pages faster.

```
 WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
 webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

this snippet is for loading any page faster, if you specifically want to load local pages only try using example explained on [This Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989766/webview-loading-local-html-page-slow-in-android)

Comment: thank you for giving me the link.I want to get the starting speed of APK,not the speed of page jump.

Comment: the setAppCachedEnabled doesn't seem to be a valid method today. Also, how will the cache mode value LOAD_NO_CACHE will improve performance when it basically tells the webview to NOT use cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) along with the web view and use the overrided method "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" and return accordingly.

Comment: if i used WebViewClient then how my webview start fastly can you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above do you also have all the external static resource locally in your app?

This is a common problem users used to load HTML content locally but its resources like JS, CSS, Fonts etc are referenced on some http URL. Apart from the Darpan's solution above you can also store your resource locally to make it even faster.

[Here are the details instructions](http://www.codewithasp.net/2016/06/speedup-android-webview-app-localise-static-resources.html) to do so.